# ESRI JavaScript API: Feature layer from x,y events

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I am trying to create a Feature Layer on the ESRI JavaScript client using the Map Service Feature layer that was created on the map document as an XY event theme (ArcMap -> File -> Add Data -> Add XY Data).  The data source for this is a 'view' on the SQL server and therefore this view doesn't have an Object ID! 
The feature Layer thus generated doesn't seem to load all the features!  Only the first fetaure is diaplayed although there are total of 7 features.

Comment: You may need to create the layer yourself using the [featureCollectionObject](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#featurelayer2) method, and supply the input features as a JSON object